# Silverlight projects no longer build automatically when I run my website

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight

I just installed Silverlight 3 + RIA services after uninstalling Silverlight 2, now my Silverlight projects no longer build automatically when I run (F5) my website. I have to manually build the silverlight app and then run the website which is really annoying. 
Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Pyt

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Right click** on website project -> **Project Dependencies..** from context menu -> **tick the box** next to silverlight project (this will make Website project dependent on SL project thus SL project will be compiled first).

And this:

**Right click** on website project -> **Properties** from context menu -> **Silverlight Applications** tab at the left and make sure that your SL applications are on the list.